# SSL Java Client for WebSphere MQ

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, ibm-mq

I try to develop a test client (Java web application) for WebSphere MQ via Spring.

I've enabled the SSL security mechanism for the channel, queue manager and connection factory, using the NULL_MD5 cipher spec.

This is my Spring configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jms.properties"/>

    <bean id="jmsFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName" value="${queue_hostname}"/>
        <property name="queueManager" value="${queue_manager}"/>
        <property name="channel" value="${queue_channel}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${queue_port}"/>
        <property name="transportType" value="1"/>
        <property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sendDestination" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <property name="baseQueueName">
            <value>queue.inbound</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
                <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
                    <ref local="jmsFactory" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestination">
            <ref bean="sendDestination" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.test.MessageListener" />

    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
                <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
                    <ref local="jmsFactory" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="destination" ref="sendDestination" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The problem is when I try to connect to the WebSphere MQ an exception raises:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'jmsContainer'; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$1(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:339)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:926)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.CipherSpec.<init>(CipherSpec.java:53)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiUtils.toCipherSuite(JmqiUtils.java:325)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.parseCipherSpec(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1984)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1838)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:810)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1130)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:710)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:400)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:299)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:164)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1223)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:311)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:337)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:346)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6876)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6254)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6189)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:120)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:203)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:225)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:403)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.establishSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:371)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.establishSharedConnection(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:750)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.doStart(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:278)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.start(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:556)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:167)
    ... 38 more
```

It is strange that even though I set the SSLCipherSuite property it tries to get the cipher suite by the cipher spec...

Can someone please suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This bug is acknowledged here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV36662

And marked as fixed in Websphere MQ fix pack 7.1.0.3.

The recommended (but not entirely satisfactory) workaround is to disable assertions in the JRE command line, with either "-disableassertions" or "-da".

Comment: Which also means anyone running into this problem as of this post would be using an unsupported version of MQ and should really look into upgrading if they hope to get support in Production.

Comment: @T.Rob 7.1 has support until the end of April :)

Comment: Senior dyslexia moment? I read that as 7.0.1.3 at first.  So, yeah, upgrade sometime in the next couple months. Not as urgent but better than discovering it *after* the expiry date, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some research it appeared that the problem is in the assertion mechanism. If assertions are disabled everything works fine. It is strange that you can have a completely working code even if assertions fail... And it is rather pity that I can't find a way to set the cipher spec - only the cipher suite setter is provided by the `MQQueueConnectionFactory` class.

In case of the weblogic server, there is a parameter named 'debugFlag' that is verified in the WLS_HOME/user_projects/domains/local-domain-name/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd (.sh). If you have it set to 'true' the application would fail. Or you can add the following JAVA_OPTION: -da:com.ibm.mq... at the end of the setDomainEnv.cmd (.sh) file. This way you can leave the debug enabled.

Of cource, it is not a preferrable way to fix the problem, but for now it is the only way I could fix it.